# How can I have markers in Time Series Plot with Python Seaborn

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

I have the following reference plot from Seaborn

```
import seaborn as sns; 
sns.set()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fmri = sns.load_dataset("fmri")
ax = sns.lineplot(x="timepoint", y="signal", hue="event", style="event", markers=True, data=fmri)
```

The above code results in the following plot:

[image]

However, when I replace the last line of the above code with this:

```
ax = sns.lineplot(x="timepoint", y="signal", markers=True, data=fmri)
```

I get the following plot:

[image]

My Question is:

How can I incorporate markers in the single plot above? It appears that the `markers = True` do not work here. Is there any way to get around with this?

Comment: Maybe you mean `marker="o"`?

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response. I have tried. But it does not work either.

Comment: It will of course work. But the question is, is that what you're after or not? And if not, how should it look like instead.